# Assistance on simplifying a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a proposed solution, but am not sure if I am correct.

I am looking to simplify a set. With only using $A, B, B', A'$ expressions.
$A, B$ are the subsets of Universe.

\begin{align}
(A' \cap \emptyset') \cap (A' \cup B') &=
A' \cap (A' \cup B')
\end{align}

I am not certain on how to simplify or statements.
Any tips on where I am wrong, and examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Next, use the distributive law.

Comment: So you mean, continue on from my progress next with using the distributive law?

Comment: I edited my post, as I had it wrong.

Comment: Distributive law:  $A' \cap (A' \cup B') = (A' \cap A') \cup (A' \cap B')$.  Note that $A' \cap A'  = A'$ and that $(A'\cap B') \subset A'$.

Comment: The complement of the empty set is that universe thing U and for any set S, S $\cap$ U = S, so the equation is immediately true.

Comment: @Bram28's edit makes nonsense of it.

Comment: @ancientmathematician You're right ... I didn't see the complement with the empty set. reverted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep doing distribution, you'll just end up going around in circles:

$$A' \cap (A' \cup B') =$$

$$ (A ' \cap A') \cup (A' \cap B') = A' \cup (A' \cap B') = (A ' \cup A') \cap (A' \cup B') = $$

$$A' \cap (A' \cup B')$$

Instead, you can do:

$$A' \cap (A' \cup B') = (A' \cup \emptyset) \cap (A' \cup B'
) = A' \cup (\emptyset \cap B') = A' \cup \emptyset = A'$$

Comment: For the last = A∪∅, should the A be the complement of A?

Comment: @Layken Yes. Typo. I'll correct it, thanks!